# How can I compute the residue at this order-2 pole?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, analyticity, singularity-theory

The integral is

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {cos(z)}{(x^2+a^2)^2}dz $$

If I use an upper semi-circular contour, then there is an order-2 pole at $z=ia$.

I am trying to expand the integrand in a Laurent expansion, centered at the pole $z=ia$ but am having some trouble getting the expansion to come out in powers of $(z-ia)$ so that I can read off the coefficient of the negative power term, $\large \frac {a_{-1}}{z-ia}$.

My attempt is, using the known series for cos(z), and writing it as

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {-1^n}{2n!}(z-ia)^{2n}$$

then multiplying by $\large \frac{1}{(z^2+a^2)^2}$ gives

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {-1^n}{2n!}\frac{(z-ia)^{2n}}{(z^2+a^2)^2}$$

$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {-1^n}{2n!}\frac{(z-ia)^{2n}}{(z-ia)^2(z+ia)^2}$$

$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {-1^n}{2n!}\frac{(z-ia)^{2(n-1)}}{(z+ia)^2}$$

and this is where I am stuck.  How can I simplify this to get it in powers of $(z-ia)$?  The $(z+ia)$ factors in the denominator seem problematic...
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may find it easier in this case to use the formula for a pole of order $n$:
$$
Res_{z_0}f(z) = \lim_{z\to z_0} \frac1{(n-1)!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}(z-z_0)^nf(z)
$$
with $z_0=ia$ and the pole of order 2 we therefore require
$$
r = \lim_{z\to ia}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{\cos z}{(z+ia)^2}
$$
since
$$
\frac{d}{dz}\frac{\cos z}{(z+ia)^2} = \frac1{(z+ia)^3}(-(z+ia)\sin z)-2\cos z)
$$
the limit is:
$$
r=-(4ia^3)^{-1}(ia\sin ia + \cos ia) \\
=\frac{i}{8a^3}(a(e^{-a}-e^a) +e^{-a}+e^{a})\\
=\frac{i}{8a^3}( (1-a)e^a +(1+a)e^{-a})
$$
(or something along these lines)
giving:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {\cos z}{(x^2+a^2)^2}dz =2\pi r \\
= \frac{\pi}{4a^3}( (1-a)e^a +(1+a)e^{-a})
$$

Comment: Hi @davidholden -- ok, I will work out the details now.  Thanks so much for your response.  I have to get better at judging when to go for a Laurent expansion or when to utilize this formula.  Have a great night :-)

Comment: i wish you all the best with your studies ;-)